# No wireless connection on HP Pavilion x360 Convertible

Tags: networking, drivers, hp, 15.10, iwlwifi

I installed Ubuntu on my new laptop, and I have problems with the wireless connection. I noticed that I wasn't able to connect to Wi-Fi since I started to install the OS, although on Windows 8.1 everything is fine. The wired connection is fine. Currently I have installed 15.04, but I tried 14.04 at first, and I also had no Wi-Fi from the very beginning of the installation. Here are the outputs of different commands:

```
$ uname -r
4.1.6-040106-generic

$ sudo lshw -c network
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 0a
   serial: 30:8d:99:1d:81:c2
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.8.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3104000-c3104fff memory:c3100000-c3103fff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 83
   serial: e4:f8:9c:6f:d0:56
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.1.6-040106-generic firmware=25.30.13.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:49 memory:c3000000-c3001fff

$ sudo iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      lo        no wireless extensions.

$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   12.627217] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   12.896955] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.579505] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   13.579836] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.580340] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   37.829851] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   37.830468] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   37.939813] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   37.940426] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   39.938588] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   39.939197] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   40.052207] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   40.052814] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  446.329043] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  446.329551] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  446.440079] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  446.440589] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT:
Due to some circumstances I had to reinstall the system, now it is 15.10. I tried the same to get rid of the problem, but it doesn't work this time. I ran the same commands and noticed that the outputs have some differences. Here they are:

```
$ uname -r
4.2.0-16-generic

sudo lshw -c network
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 0a
       serial: 30:8d:99:1d:81:c2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.8.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3104000-c3104fff memory:c3100000-c3103fff
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 83
       serial: e4:f8:9c:6f:d0:56
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.2.0-16-generic firmware=15.227938.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:c3000000-c3001fff

sudo iwconfig
wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   10.586455] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   11.180749] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.227938.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   11.730991] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   11.731488] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   11.732000] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   11.911089] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[   31.820881] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   31.821389] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   31.935450] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Many thanks in advance for any attempt to help!

Comment: It was a bad idea to edit the question with an answer to ask a new question. You could ask a new question and refer to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot. That should fix the issue.

You can undo this setting by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

Comment: An enormous thank you! It fixed everything straightaway!

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but the solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @BlueMagma Do you have the "exact same" wireless adapter? Please ask a new question and provide the details.

Comment: This helped me. I've recently acquired a HP Pavilion x360 Convertible. If you're using vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 LTS make sure you upgrade the kernel to 4.2.x http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/08/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-2-0-in-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate answer which doesn't disable 802.11n. Blacklist the acer_wmi module. Create a file called /etc/modprobe.d/acer_wmi.conf and put this inside of it:

```
# acer_wmi conflicts with iwlwifi/nm which this HP x360 laptop uses
# (Your name, today's date)
blacklist  acer_wmi
```

By the way, I tried this on an HP Pavilion x360 Convertible m1-u001dx.

Answer (score 1):

(edited as requested)

For everyone out there having problems with the wifi in this laptop, this was what truly worked for me (adapting some commands from Arch to Ubuntu by googling). This was tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.10 successfully without requiring any other instructions.

The answer from hackerb9 to deactivate de acer_wmi module and instructions from here: [rtl8723be wifi connection issues solved by antenna selection](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208472)

Just change the following commands that appear in that guide for this ones:

---

**Arch command**

pacman -S base-devel git linux-headers iw rfkill wireless_tools

**Ubuntu command**

sudo apt-get install build-essential iw linux-headers-generic git  rfkill wireless-tools

---

**Arch command**

sudo mkinitcpio -p linux

**Ubuntu command**

sudo update-initramfs -u

And my configuration file looks like this:
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N swlps=N swenc=Y disable_watchdog=1 ant_sel=2

**NOTE:** Don't update the kernel of the OS if you are not on a wired network, updating the kernel will require that you repeat the steps on the guide.

As last step:

sudo echo "blacklist acer-wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Then reboot and that's it!

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Link-only answers are not of good quality. Please consider expanding your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the internet by some other way and install the 4.8+ kernel

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

You also need firmware for this device. Update your system by

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and the firmware will be installed.

Reboot and the wireless device should work.

To get it working out of the box, you need to install Ubuntu 16.04.2+ that has support of this device.
(I used a USB Ethernet connector for internet access. )

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.