# Ubuntu 16.04 on HP Pavilion x360 convertible model: 13-u102ng

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, hardware

Bluetooth and wifi are not working and I can't connect via ethernet because there is no socket for it.

First, I tuned it, when it arrived:

- replacing 1tb hdd with 1tb ssd
- adding another 8gb ram in order to get 16gb in total

Maybe I broke or forgot to connect something, when I tuned my laptop. Maybe I did not. I'm not sure, since many others have problems with the wifi on Ubuntu with this HP.

I blacklisted `acer_wmi` in `/etc/modeprobe.d/blacklist-acer_wmi.conf`. That fixed the problem with the airplane mode, which always immediately jumped back on.
But still no wifi... The network in the settings says: airplane mode off. Network Proxy.

I tried a lot of stuff yesterday when browsing the www for solutions, but I only remember this one: [No wireless connection on HP Pavilion x360 Convertible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677621/no-wireless-connection-on-hp-pavilion-x360-convertible)

Comment: Could you add more info on what you've tried so we can give useful suggestions?

Comment: Well, if I just could remember all of that stuff I tried, brndn2k... I remember this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/677621/no-wireless-connection-on-hp-pavilion-x360-convertible

Comment: I can reinstall Ubuntu in order to start "fresh".

Comment: Is Wi-Fi off? Or are there just no wifi visible?

Comment: There is no option for turning on/off wifi.

Comment: What do you see in the network settings? In the settings manager

Comment: Too bad I can't send you an image... Network proxy. Airplane mode is off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No wireless connection on HP Pavilion x360 Convertible](http://askubuntu.com/questions/677621/no-wireless-connection-on-hp-pavilion-x360-convertible)

Comment: not a duplicate, but a hardware issue (see the answer) reviewers please vote no-repro :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @brndn2k for your comments, they helped to get a stronger awkward feeling, that something is wrong with the hardware.

So, I opened up my HP again.
Found the Bluetooth/Wifi chip.
It wasn't fully connected. - I am happy, I didn't break it!
So, I connected it properly.
And, yep, it is working now.

Comment: Good for you! If this fixed it you may want to accept it as the answer.